# Does GKE Autopilot manages autoscaling by default?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Good morning. I am doing some tests with the new Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine's Autopilot mode. I know that it automates a lot of the machine resources' management, but I am not sure about what it automates. Does it only cares about provisioning the hardware resources that I set inside my PodSpec? Or does it also cares about scaling up and down the number of containers that I have based on traffic intensity?

I am coming from Cloud Run, so, after all, my main question is: Now, with GKE Autopilot, do I need to do something for it to create new container instances when the traffic intensity increases or is it all automatically managed? Do I need to set HPA, VPA and other autoscaler technologies when using autopilot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GKE autopilot you need to create the **HPA** and **VPA** configuration

GKE autopilot will the scaling of **Node** by default

You can read more at : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#comparison

> Scaling   Pre-configured: Autopilot handles all the scaling and
> configuring of your nodes.
>
> Default: You configure Horizontal pod autoscaling (HPA) You configure
> Vertical Pod autoscaling (VPA)
>
> Do I need to set HPA, VPA and other autoscaler technologies when using
> autopilot?

**Autoscaler** is not required as it will be by default managed by GKE and will scale the Node as per requirement.

Comment: Good. So let's see if I understood: Autopilot will just handle the nodes, but I am the one who defines how big the pods will be (via PodSpec) and when and how the pods will scale (via HPA or VPA).

Comment: Also, would I be able to 'downscale' when the traffic intensity decreases? If yes, I would use HPA, VPA or something else?

Comment: Yes you have to set resource limit and request for sure to HPA to work. And hpa also

Comment: it auto downscae why you need to downscale manually ? yes HPA and VPA will work with atuoscaler so once your pod scale down by HPA and VPA autoscaler will reduce the number of Nodes also in cluster.